# ColorStateList and TextColor not being applied using CustomAttr in ToggleButton in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have a custom class called `SkinableToggleButton` which extends `ToggleButton` of Android. Its code is as below:

```
public class SkinableToggleButton extends ToggleButton {

public SkinableToggleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public SkinableToggleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    //Applied custom font/typeface here
    init(context, attrs);
}

protected void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (isInEditMode()) return;

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Skinable, 0, 0);

    try {
        if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.Skinable_skinableTextColor)) {
            int textColorSkin = a.getInt(R.styleable.Skinable_skinableTextColor, 0);
            SkinUtil.applyTextColorTheme(this, textColorSkin);//Applying custom text color through custom attr
        }

        if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.Skinable_skinableSrcTint)) {
int backgroundTintSkin = a.getInt(R.styleable.Skinable_skinableSrcTint, 0);
            int checkedColor = SkinUtil.getColor(backgroundTintSkin);//util method returning correct color
            int disabledColor = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.grey_3);
            int[][] states = new int[][]{
            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked}, // checked
            new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
            new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled} // disabled
    };
    int[] colors = new int[]{
            checkedColor,
            checkedColor,
            checkedColor,
            disabledColor
    };

    compoundButton.setButtonTintList(new ColorStateList(states, colors));
        }
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}}
```

In XML, I have used it as follows:

```
<SkinableToggleButton
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   style="@style/tiny_toggle_button"
   android:textOff="Connect"
   android:textOn="Connected"/>
```

Style `tiny_toggle_button` code:

```
<style name="tiny_toggle_button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_toggle_btn</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/spacing_5x</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/sp_12</item>
    <item name="android:lineHeight">@dimen/sp_16</item>
    <item name="android:letterSpacing">0.0175</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/selector_toggle_bg</item>
    <item name="skinableSrcTint">primary1</item> <!--Custom Attr-->
</style>
```

`selector_toggle_btn` drawable:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="true" >
        <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/spacing_0_5x"/>
            <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="@color/black"
            />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/spacing_0_5x"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white_1"/>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/spacing_0_5x"/>
            <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="@color/grey_4"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

`selector_toggle_bg` in color:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/white_1"/>
    <!-- Default State -->
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="false"
          android:color="@color/black"/>
    <item android:color="@color/grey_3" android:state_enabled="false"/>
</selector>
```

***Problem:***
My custom attrs (**Tint colors and text colors**) are not being applied from selector drawable and color files. My drawable and text color selector is working perfectly fine except for my custom attrs. Am I doing something wrong with the `custom attrs` and applying `ColorStateList`? I have set my custom attr `skinableSrcTint` in my custom style in styles.xml. Custom style's code has already been pasted above.

I am not very much experienced at posting questions on StackOverflow. Please let me know if any other detail is required, I will edit it and post detail/or in comments.

Comment: > Though, It is working fine if I apply them directly in main xml instead of applying in selectors.

Do you mean that that your custom attributes get applied if you use them in the layout xml? or not in a selector, but in your drawable xml?

Comment: You need to use `ColorStateList` for state control of color in Java or Kotlin file and use `reference` as format in `attrs.xml`. `Drawable` state get automatically handled if you are using selector.

Comment: Hi @drdaanger I have added more details to the question. Kindly refer. Brief: Actually my selectors are being applied only. No custom attr is being applied.

Comment: Hi @MostafaMonowar I am already using `ColorStateList` and using `reference` in `attrs.xml` My drawable is working but custom attr is not being applied. I have updated the code in the question. Kindly have a look.

Comment: need to create selector programmatically and set the background

Comment: Type of int `backgroundTintSkin` should be `ColorStateList` instead of `int`

Comment: At this point, I think screenshots of what you are seeing would be helpful. Seeing your attrs.xml might be helpful as well.